# Heroku-Github Auto Deploy from non-master (only see master branch)

Tags: heroku

[FYI - I am not looking to upgrade our Heroku account to Enterprise to take advantage of app grouping. We are a small team]

I am a collaborator on a heroku app. I was tasked with setting up dev-staging-production environments for the app and I am getting confused on how to setup Auto Deploy correctly with the GitHub-Heroku integration guide. I have been already given admin access to the original git repo.

From the 'owner' account on the production app I created two separate apps (dev and staging).

Now, I have 3 apps that I am a collaborator of:

> (1) app.domain.com
>   (2) app-dev.domain.com
>   (3) app-staging.domain.com

I have created 3 remotes pointing to the 3 generated heroku-git repos:

> live
>   dev
>   staging

I can push to the 3 Heroku apps easily by:

> git push live master 
>   git push dev master 
>   git push staging master

BUT I want to setup auto-deploy for dev-staging apps.

I have pushed an "auto" branch onto dev and staging remote. My intention is for Heroku to detect pushes to that branch and "auto" deploy the code. But, heroku only detects pushes to "master" branch afaik.

> git push dev release auto 
>   git push staging release auto

But when I go to administer the Heroku dev-staging apps I only see the "master" branch in the Auto-deploy section. Shouldn't I also see the "auto" branch? Is the reason I am not seeing it because I didn't push auto as a remote branch on the ORIGINAL git repo? In which case, how do I structure this stuff as code lives in 2 separate environments (Heroku repo and GitHub repo)?

Ultimately, the plan is to setup some form of Continuous Integration and get tests run before releases happen across the dev-staging-production zones.

Am I overthinking this or is there a better way to get this stuff working? Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

**Heroku only tracks changes on the remote `master` Branch.**

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-from-a-branch-besides-master

To push your `dev` branch to the Heroku `master` remote branch:

```sh
git push dev release:master
```

*You may need to use the `-f` flag to force push (be careful!)*

Answer (score 0):

I think auto deploy on Heroku works only on default branch (usually named master), and you probably want to look into Heroku feature called [pipelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines). I've not used it myself yet and it's in beta stage, but it sounds like exactly what you're looking for. Not sure if I read it right, but it sounds like you created 3 individual projects, instead of branches in 1 project? How do you manage moving changes from one stage to another?

As for the CI setup I guess it depends on the kind of testing you're doing and the workflow. I'm in the middle of creating such process in my workplace, and what I will be proposing is as follows:

- Devs develop and test on their local machines on feature branches before commiting and merging onto DEV branch
- Commiting or merging onto the DEV branch triggers CI server, runs the build and perform PHPUnit and Behat tests
- Successful build is being deployed to a server (possibly Heroku or any hosting provider that will support automated deployments) for QA.
- Once tested and approved we can move the code onto STAGING branch repeat CI proccess and on success move to MASTER and go live.

We're using gilab.com to host our project and perform tests (CI server is included as standard even with free account), deploy dev and staging state for QA to Heroku, and finally host live version with a dedicated enterprise level provider.